# Visualising pattern matching in JavaScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a naive pattern matching function, and I'm trying to slow down execution of each comparison so I can create a visualiser for it. However, I want to be able to access my i and j variables outside of the function. I am attempting to do this by declaring them outside of the function, passing them in, and returning them after each match. This way I can press a button to control the flow of execution. However, they are not being returned properly, and I suspect this has something to do with my use of async/await, and the need to return the values as a Promise.

https://codesandbox.io/s/staging-http-0zm04?file=/src/App.tsx:0-1072

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";


const delay = (ms) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

export const naive = async (text: string, pattern: string, i: number, j: number) => {
    const matches = [];
    let n = text.length;
    let m = pattern.length;
    while (i < n){
        while (j < pattern.length && pattern[j] === text[i + j]){
            j += 1;
            await delay(500);
        }
        if (j === m){
            matches.push(i)
        }
        return [i, j, matches]
    }
}

export default function App() {

    const [text, setText] = useState<string>("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcd")
    const [pat, setPat] = useState<string>("abc")
    const [i, updateI] = useState(0);
    const [j, updateJ] = useState(0);

    const nextMatch = () => {
      let results = naive(text, pat, i, j);
      updateI(results[0]);
      updateJ(results[1]);
  }

  return (
    <div>
    <button style = {{width: "100px", height: "50px"}}onClick = {() => nextMatch()}/>
      {i}
      {j}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: The function `naive` returns a promise so `results` is a promise. That means that `results[0]` is undefined. You could try `naive(text, pat, i, j).then(resulst=>{updateI(results[0];updateJ(results[1]))}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As navie is an async function you have to add **then**.This would help to return correct i and j values

```js
const nextMatch = () => {
  naive(text, pat, i, j).then((results) => {
    updateI(results[0]);
    updateJ(results[1]);
  });
};
```